# How to get direct link of HD Netflix banners/posters/thumbnails

Tags: netflix, inspect-element, poster

I am only able to get upto 300px through inspect elements
how people are able to get this much resolution

Here is an example:
Like this links I want to get.

https://occ-0-1168-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/rkETp35xJVj-6WaffQsS77awykM/AAAABYMgWCQ1pvFXLzjC1jM21tQc46UGM1mjAKKg7RuYOvSgK_7wSYqqR1MbPwpTY5VNGDcjTO1VmNoAwHg3fTPkMFZGHtgo2r-s8mIk87FW2Hs4FXTFBlnp9zExIRjGc4_BgjPrdA.jpg?r=062

Please help me get those, In unogs I also saw people gave high resolution banners